# Exception window in VS.NET 2010 is missing the "User-unhandled" column

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio **2008**, the Exceptions window has two columns with check boxes:

[image: Visual Studio 2008]

In contrast to this, in Visual Studio **2010** the column seems to be missing:

[image: Visual Studio 2010]

My questions are:

- Is this a configuration issue on my machine or "by design"?
- Do I have a chance to re-enable the column or to mimic the "user-unhandled" behaviour in a different way?

**Update:**

The following extensions are installed in my Visual Studio 2010 installation:

- PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010
- Productivity Power Tools
- Visual Studio Color Theme Editor
- VisualSVN
- ReSharper

Answer (score 92, accepted):

My installation of Visual Studio 2010 does have the "User-unhandled" column:

[image]

**Edit**

From [VS2008 Debugger does not break on unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103034/vs2008-debugger-does-not-break-on-unhandled-exception)...

> As it turns out, if you do not have "Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)" checked in the Debug options, the "User-Unhandled" column does not show in the "Exceptions" dialog.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. Maybe it is a setting of an extension I have installed. I'll investigate.

Comment: @Uwe, please see my edit. I think that might be your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, that really was it! Stack Overflow and their users really rock!

Comment: Yes, but how do you uncheck user-unhandled exceptions for C++?