# catch exception from included dll project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have included a DLL project in my solution. From the main project I can normally debug, use breakpoints and so on. But if there is an exception I only get the information in the console and the debugger is not jumping there.

To be more specific, it is a WPF project where the DLL project is included as a UserControl. How to see where the exceptions are coming from? Try/Catch is a little bit of a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of exception window

pres CTRL + D, E

[image]

Comment: What is the reason I do not see this User-unhandled?

Comment: @user2799180 - i m not sure but i use this window to catch the location of exection i.e. code which is throwing exception

Comment: You need to have "Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)" checked in the debug settings. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4560642/1346943)