# Visual C# Debugger not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Something is seriously wrong with my VS Debugger. I run my application and do a specific task and it produces an exception 'A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll', thats all well and good but it just crashes my app when I expect the debugger to kick in and show me where the exception occurred. The project is set to Debug and the debugger is attached. So why is it not working as it should?

Comment: Are you attaching the debugger to a remote process? If so, I think you'll need the PDB of the assembly in order for it to be debuggable.

Comment: It does 2 projects both managed, both have PDBs available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable [Exception handling in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364744/c-sharp-exception-handling-somehow-i-am-doing-it-wrong), it should help to you yo stop on *exact* possible row where source code and debug data (PDB) are available.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I shall mark as the answer after the time ;)